# Change outer ul background color when inner li has a class="selected"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some menus with unordered list (`ul`):

```
<ul class="myul">
  <li>Button1</li>
  <li>Button2</li>
  <li class="selected">Button3</li>
  <li>Button4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="myul">
  <li>Button5</li>
  <li>Button6</li>
  <li>Button7</li>
  <li>Button8</li>
</ul>
```

and so on...

How i can change with jQuery the background color of outer `ul` when the inner `li` has `class="selected"`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use method `closest()` or `parent()`. Here is an example using method `closest()`.

Method `closest()` target a parent of *any level* relative to a child.

Method `parent()` only target the *first level* parent.

This is a jQuery solution:

```js
$('li.selected').closest('ul').css('background', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="myul">
    <li>Button1</li>
    <li>Button2</li>
    <li class="selected">Button3</li>
    <li>Button4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="myul">
    <li>Button5</li>
    <li>Button6</li>
    <li>Button7</li>
    <li>Button8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you my friend. it worked with parent().

Answer (score -1):

This would be a job for the "has" selector in CSS. Unfortunately, as of this writing, there's almost no browser support for it. Safari Technology Preview "cutting edge" browser has support, and that's just about it.

https://caniuse.com/?search=has

You can search for "css parent selector" to see how this has been a longstanding request among many web developers.